# Getting List of Integers from List of Array of Objects

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I have my resultset in List of array of objects. I want to get values in an Integer list using java stream.

```
 List<Object[]> to List<Integer> in java8.
```

I was trying to achieve like this.But it is giving me exception.
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Object;

```
List<Integer> integers = record.stream()
        .flatMap(o-> Arrays.stream(o))
        .map(ob->Integer.valueOf((Integer) ob))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am new to functional programming. Please let me know why i am getting exception and how it works.

Thanks,
Prabhash

Comment: Please show a complete, runnable example which illustrates the problem.

Comment: please share the type of record object.

Comment: Your exception implies that the elements of your record are not Integers. You might require some additional mapping.

Comment: What you have done is right, but try to use method reference Array::stream

Answer (score -1):

I've tried your code and it's working

```
Object[] ob = new Object[2];
    ob[0] = 0;
    ob[1] = 1;
    List<Object[]> record = new ArrayList<>();
    record.add(ob);
    List<Integer> integers = record.stream()
            .flatMap(o-> Arrays.stream(o))
            .map(obb-> (Integer) obb)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    integers.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This line is fine. An array of objects is being flat mapped to create one stream of single elements.

Comment: Notice that the question's `record` is `List<Object[]>` not just `List<Object>`